# Update a field, depending on another field with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am just trying to replicate something that you can do using the mongodb driver (the first answer),
[Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

```
db.collection.<update method>(
    {},
    [
        {
          "$set": {   
             "todayHours" : "$tomorrowHours",
            "tomorrowHours" : "2" 
          }
        }
    ]
)
```

The code I have on mongoose is

```
this.userModel.updateMany({},{
            "todayHours" : "$tomorrowHours",
            "tomorrowHours" : "2"
})
```

But it won't work as expected
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

should be like:

```
.updateMany(
   {'your condition here'},
   {$set:{
            todayHours : "$tomorrowHours",
            tomorrowHours : "2"
         }
   }
)
```

Comment: Same output sadly

Comment: do you know which version are you running by any chance?

Comment: mongoose 5.9.12